# Weird pwd glitch in .sh file

Tags: shell, cmd, cygwin, git-bash, pwd

I am trying to set up DeepLab, and in the process I have to run a .sh file. Unfortunately, I must use Windows, so I am using Git Bash to run the file. Previously, I had Cygwin downloaded (since deleted). While running the .sh file, it uses pwd to run various commands, but it always errors because the pwd command when ran through the .sh file will return the path with /cygdrive/ prepending it. Any ideas on what might be happening?

Running pwd on Git Bash terminal gives the proper path (no /cygdrive/ at the beginning) and I have tried reinstalling cygdrive just to uninstall again. Not really sure where to go from here. I ran dos2unix after I edit the .sh file, so it shouldn't be an issue there.

Problematic code in the .sh file that I am running:

```
# Set up the working environment.
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)
# added below line to see what pwd returned
echo ${CURRENT_DIR}
WORK_DIR="${CURRENT_DIR}/deeplab"

# Run model_test first to make sure the PYTHONPATH is correctly set.
python "${WORK_DIR}"/model_test.py -v
```

Running the .sh file in git bash gives the following output:

```
guptav3@IMPH9074 MINGW64 /b/George/Vyas_Gupta/tensorflow/models/research/deeplab (master)
$ sh local_test.sh
/cygdrive/b/George/Vyas_Gupta/tensorflow/models/research
C:\Users\guptav3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/b/George/Vyas_Gupta/tensorflow/models/research/deeplab/model_test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Notice that the echo ${CURRENT_DIR} prepends /cygdrive to the path desired.

Running pwd command in Git Bash gives the expected output:

```
guptav3@IMPH9074 MINGW64 /b/George/Vyas_Gupta/tensorflow/models/research/deeplab (master)
$ pwd
/b/George/Vyas_Gupta/tensorflow/models/research/deeplab
```

Some other information:

```
$ ldd $(which pwd)
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77c90000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x77a70000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fefd8d0000)
        SYSFER.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/System32/SYSFER.DLL (0x754c0000)
        ADVAPI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/ADVAPI32.dll (0x7feff910000)
        msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/msvcrt.dll (0x7fefe9d0000)
        sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/sechost.dll (0x7fefef80000)
        RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7feffcf0000)
        msys-intl-8.dll => /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/msys-intl-8.dll (0x430b30000)
        msys-iconv-2.dll => /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/msys-iconv-2.dll (0x5603f0000)
        msys-2.0.dll => /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/msys-2.0.dll (0x180040000)
        DNSAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/DNSAPI.dll (0x7fefcdb0000)
        WS2_32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/WS2_32.dll (0x7feffc90000)
        NSI.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/NSI.dll (0x7feffce0000)

$ printenv | grep cygdrive
PATH=/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/local/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/HP/HP Performance Advisor:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018b/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018b/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2017b/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2017b/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2017a/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2017a/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016a/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016a/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Webex/Webex/Applications:/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Launcher:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: Show us the output from `ldd $(which pwd)` and `printenv | grep cygdrive` please. The first is to check that you use a git bash and not a cygwin bash pwd. The second looks for anything in the environment that uses  cygdrive.

Comment: Hi Doug, the response is as follows. I was already pretty confident that this was some issue with uninstalling Cygwin. I added your requests to the main post. Any thoughts of where to go from here?

Comment: Looking at your PATH reinforces my idea of trying with a *simplified* PATH, as I detail in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again in a CMD where you launch a git bash session *after* having set a simplified PATH (to avoid any lingering side-effect of an old PATH)

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Path\to\Python\Python36;%PATH%
```

(Modify `C:\Path\to\Git` and `C:\Path\to\Python\Python36` by your Git and Python installation paths)

Then try again.